# Using conditional formatting in pandas using lambda

Tags: pandas, lambda

I have a column in my pandas dataframe which goes like this:

```
Size 
19M
14M
160k
..
..
```

I now need to extract the numeric part from each cell, and if the previous value contains a "M", the numeric part needs to be multiplied by 1000. In Excel, I've used this formula

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="M",LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1)*1000,LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1))
```

How do I replicate this in pandas?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

One way could be: Mask the rows where the previous row has a `M`, then change the values conditionally with `np.where`. `fillna(False)` is for the first row, since there is no previous row to compare `shift` will result in `Nan`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Size": {0: "19M", 
                            1: "14M", 
                            2: "160k", 
                            3: "5M", 
                            4: "17k", 
                            5: "7M"}})

mask = df['Size'].shift().str.contains('M').fillna(False)
print(mask)

df['res'] = np.where(mask, df['Size'].str[:-1].astype(int)*1000, df['Size'].str[:-1].astype(int))
print(df)

#mask
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: Size, dtype: bool

#df
   Size     res
0   19M      19
1   14M   14000
2  160k  160000
3    5M       5
4   17k   17000
5    7M       7
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution uses LAG & REGEX

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['19M','14M','160K','17M','100K']})

df['col1_lag'] = df['col1'].shift(1)

df[['col1','col1_lag']].apply(lambda x: int(re.sub("[^/0-9]",'',x[0])) * 100 if str(x[1]).endswith('M') else int(re.sub("[^/0-9]",'',x[0])), axis = 1)
```

Output:

[image]